# C# - десереализация JSON без описания класса

Tags: c#, json

Возникла необходимость, получать от серверной стороны данные в формате JSON, и далее с ними работать.
В ответ на запрос прилетает массив обьектов в JSON (сообщения чата), которые необходимо распасить / либо десереализовать в объект.
Однако любые мануалы по C#, в вопросах сериализации / десереализации сначала описывают объект, сериализуют его, и далее - десереализуют JSON на основании вышеописанного класса.
Неужели обязательно перед десереализацией описывать класс, на основании которого будет десереализовываться объект?

Ведь JSON фактически уже содержит названия полей и данные в них, возможно как либо десереализовать JSON сразу в объект и с ним работать?

Comment: Дело в том, что сделав опечатку в классе, вы получите ошибку, сделав изменение в классе - вы получите в других местах ошибки (где используется), также вы не обязаны постоянно вспоминать, что у вас в массиве "ААА" есть свойство "МегаСвойство33", которое содержит в себе еще "массивБ" и так далее, вам студия будет выдавать подсказки, ибо это объекты класса. Вот для этого и существует десериализация в класс. Ну а так, вы можете всегда сделать `JObject.Parse()["МегаСвойство"]` (это JSON.NET), но потом не расстраивайтесь, если у вас ответ поменяется и вы забудете поменять где-то название свойства.

Comment: Возможно некорректно донес вопрос - формат API на стороне сервера точно меняться не будет, это стандартизированный API. Моя цель - хоть как то работать с JSON, который приходит в ответ. И я вижу только два пути - парсить вручную, либо использовать механизмы десереализации.

Comment: Дело ваше, я вам сказал все плюсы сериализации в класс. Если у вас всего 1 вызов, то можете и по ключу брать нужное значение, но если у вас в классе тысячи вызовов этого свойства, то думайте сами, в дальнейшем вам как в дальнейшем вам лучше будет писать приложение и отлавливать все косяки.

Comment: Если у вас есть класс для десериализации, то вы считай парсите json одной строчкой. Если у вас нет такого класса и вы его не хотите использовать, то вам придется парсить json вручную. Выбирайте сами что вам из этого больше подходит.

Comment: Что именно - какую библиотеку - используете для работы с json? Так-то, как уже сказали в первом комментарии, можно использовать JObject.